# Calcular o peso de cada classe de um dataset multi-label não balancado

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

Gostaria de calcular o peso de cada classe de um *dataset* *multi-label* para passar pro `fit_generator` do Keras o parâmetro `class_weight`. No caso de um dataset *single-label*, como minha saída é limitada a exclusivamente uma classe, consigo calcular como o exemplo abaixo:

```
def calc_weight_single_label(label_count):
    max_value = max(label_count.values())
    class_weight = {}
    for key in label_count.keys():
        class_weight[key] = max_value/label_count[key]
    return class_weight

>>> # class A:10%, class B:50% and class C:40%
>>> labels_dict = {'A':10, 'B':50, 'C':40}
>>> calc_weight_single_label(labels_dict)
    {'A': 5.0, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.25}
```

Isto significa que a perda quando classificar a classe `A` erroneamente será 5 vezes maior que se classificar `B` erroneamente.

Porém, em um *dataset multi-label*, posso ter classificações como: apenas `A`, `A` e `B`, `A` e `C` e assim por diante. Como posso calcular o peso de cada classe neste caso?

Um exemplo seria este dicionário com as ocorrências `labels_dict = {'A':10, 'B':50, 'C':40, 'D':20}` e um número total de amostras igual a `100`.

Comment: Como assim você pode existir classificação A e B? Não entendi!!! Por exemplo você quer classificar se uma pessoa está saudável, doente ou morta. Na sua descrição você poderia classificar que a pessoa está saudável e morta ou doente e morta? Estranho hein ...

Comment: Neste exemplo de estar saudável, doente ou morta, a classificação é single-label. Um exemplo de multi-label são classes como: classe A é 0 para idade < 18 e 1 para idade > 18, classe B é 0 para não ser estudante e 1 para ser. Ai uma classificação pode ser tanto A e B, quanto só A, só B ou nenhuma.

Comment: @AlexCiuffa qual método do Keras você está utilizando para fazer esse treinamento? Preciso entender a estratégia multi-label sendo utilizada para dar uma resposta mais adequada.

Comment: Estou usando o `.fit_generator()`. O gerador é algo parecido com o `flow_from_dataframe()`, mas customizado. Meus labels estão em um dataframe em uma coluna `labels`. Um exemplo de duas linhas seria: `[1,0,0,1]` e `[0,0,1,1]`

Comment: Acho que não fui muito claro, mas quero saber qual classificador você está utilizando. Não sou especialista em Keras mas pelo que entendi o .fit_generator() é só uma forma de treinar com batches de forma mais flexível.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a pergunta. Estou usando uma arquitetura CNN, seguido de uma rede fully-connected e, na ultima camada, saídas com sigmoide como função de ativação. Se iso não responde a pergunta, poderia me dar um exemplo de classificadores?